# Asp.Net/Javascript Avoid postback on click on button inside bulleted list, meanwhile call a function from code behind on click event

Tags: c#, asp.net, postback, bulletedlist

i have an asp bulleted list with link buttons into list items. I need to avoid the postback action called on click on the button; meanwhile, on click event, i have to call a function from code behind. 
Anyone knows how i can do it?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

To access the code behind you either need a post back on an ajax query.

To STOP the post back onclick set the control autopostback to false:

```
<asp:ListControl AutoPostBack="False" />
```

[ListControl.AutoPostBack Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.autopostback%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) 
not too sure what you want to achieve here.